# Having a issue with permalinks in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, permalinks

I have been working on a site locally but forgot to change the permalinks from "default" to "post name". If I change the option to "post name" none of my links work, even though when I go onto the page or post the URL is for example ...localhost://mysite/about but when I enter localhost/mysite/about I get "NOT FOUND" in the browser.

How can I fix the problem I am having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if mod_rewrite was enabled on your local server? Are you using wamp, xampp or something else?

Did not read it entirely but have a look at this -> http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I'm using WAMP. Is that in the config file?

Comment: yes. look for {wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf. But localhost://mysite is not a correct url for wamp, is it? it is always http://localhost/ ....

Comment: You can activate mod_rewrite in wamp through the GUI menu. Left click on the WAMP-icon in the activity bar, Select Apache > Apache Modules and make sure that rewrite_module is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've managed to resolve the problem I was having  from your advice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

please go to Settings-> Permalink and again select "Post Name" Option And Click Save Button

Comment: Hi I know how to change the permalinks the problem was that the site was not recognizing the new permalinks.